# Issues in writing jasmine Karma test cases for angular 4 App

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

While writing test cases for angular 4 app we are facing some issues.

1)Unable to create fixture Textbed object of service/component when they have methods which deal with HTML tags.

(e.g.

overlayOn() { document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block"; }
overlayOff() {document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none"; }

)

Error :unable to set style of undefined.

2)Issue in mocking ViewChild() , EventEmitter(),@Output() and @Input() elements.

Error :unable to set property of undefined.

Basically whenever we are dealing with html Tags in type script code, then we are getting errors in writing test cases.

Please help if there is any way to mock or set these tags in test cases.

Comment: Check this https://github.com/shashankvivek/Angular4/tree/master/Karma_Tests/src/app/components for reference.

Comment: Thanks for prompt response. Let me check and will get back to you.

Comment: Dear Shashank , checked all ts file in above URL. HTML tags not used in any ts file . Can you please provide any reference where i can get example ?

Comment: The issue of mocking html tags used in TypeScript code is still exist.

Comment: Can you share your code whatever you have written (even if its not working). I'll try to fix that. I used some html tags in the ref provided.

Comment: Thanks shashank for prompt response. I would like to mock below sample code. document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none"

Comment: Can you check and confirm on my answer

Comment: Shashank , thanks a lot . below solution worked. I need one more help.  I will share u sample service code which i would like to mock by eod.

Comment: Ashish, IMHO , please dont expect the complete solution of any problem on SO. you need to put your effort and we can try to solve that specific issue rather than solving the complete business problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

For HTML:

```
    <div id="overlay" style="display: none"></div>
```

the js file:

```
it('should not display id "overlay"', () => {
    let containerElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#overlay')).nativeElement.style.display;
    expect(containerElement).toBe('none');
})
```